# Rails adds weird anchors to my URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Video` model. I am using `link_to` to link the a specifiic video. When I access the video page, Rails apprends to the URL weird anchors like this `#.UBbC5zF2bZ8`. I think it has something to do with my `to_params`method :

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{title.parameterize}"
end
```

And my `link_to` code :

```
= link_to image_tag(video.thumb, size:"260x145"), video_path(video)
```

Comment: A `video` entry? What's that? How do you generate the link?

Comment: Whats your link_to code look like?

Comment: Edited my question `= link_to image_tag(video.thumb, size:"260x145"), video_path(video)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to rails.

It's a feature of a sharing/tracking plugin called AddThis.

Here's a similar question on their support page:
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/370666-addthis-adds-a-random-number-onto-my-urls

Comment: You are so right! I never though it could be AddThis. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! Glad you got to see my response, after so long--I was mostly leaving it for anyone else who ran across your unanswered question, which I did, when I had the same problem.